# Extra spacing added in foundation 4 with custom wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress-theming, zurb-foundation

I am working with Foundation 4 plus WP and came across a very interesting issue and this is not a UTF-8 issue.

Page rendering in Chrome:
http://www.nmjgraphics.com/imaging/chrome_ren.jpg

Page rendering in Firefox (IE 10 loads the same way):
http://www.nmjgraphics.com/imaging/ff_ren.jpg

In both FF and IE the top navigation renders perfect out of the box, but in chrome it is bumped down by 30px. Now I can apply a margin of -1.9% 0% 0% 24.5% and that gets the menu back to where is "should" be on the browser, but IE and FF shift the menu by -1.9% and that cuts the navigation in half. In addition to that I also tried using the top element setting at 100% initially and then using "inspect element" in chrome move the number down to 0 with no effect at all.

This has not been tested on Opera or Safari, but my assumption is they will render just like FF and IE.

I do apologize for the links instead of images, but I need 10 rep just to add images to the question and I can only post two links, but I did have a total of 3 images showing the rendering on the three browsers. If you want to see the ie rendering, just change the browser name to ie_ren.jpg.

Comment: sorry I ran out of links, but here is the link to the blog http://lab.nmjgraphics.com

Comment: I just found this little gem in my source code on the site. I think it is the root of the problem, it is the top bar that wp uses in twenty eleven

`<style type="text/css" media="screen">
 html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
 * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>`

Comment: I just solved it myself. I was pulling my hair out for nothing. Page renders fine if I am not logged in. I completely forgot about the bar. I figured that if I wasn't placing it in the theme it wouldn't show up at all. Learned something new there. I will either add the bar (which I should) or disable it all together.

annoying this site can be as I am barred from answering my own question for 8 hours. So if someone can click on solved, it would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

solved it. I was pulling my hair out for nothing. Page renders fine if I am not logged in. I completely forgot about the bar. I figured that if I wasn't placing it in the theme it wouldn't show up at all. Learned something new there. I will either add the bar (which I should) or disable it all together.